# Evernote Android-Job: не работает

Tags: android

Ребята, я сделал вроде бы всё по примеру, но уведомления приходят минут 30-40,а после закрытия приложения в диспетчере, уведомления не приходят.

Почему?

**MyJob**

```
public class MyJob extends Job{
    public static final String TAG = "job_demo_tag";
    @NonNull
    @Override
    protected Result onRunJob(@NonNull Params params) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Работает",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(getContext(), 0,
                new Intent(getContext(), MainActivity.class), 0);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getContext())
                .setContentTitle("Android Job Demo")
                .setContentText("Notification from Android Job Demo App.")
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(pi)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setShowWhen(true)
                .setColor(Color.RED)
                .setLocalOnly(true)
                .build();

        NotificationManagerCompat.from(getContext())
                .notify(new Random().nextInt(), notification);

        return Result.SUCCESS;
    }


    public static void schedulePeriodicJob() {
        new JobRequest.Builder(MyJob.TAG)
                .setPeriodic(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(15), TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(5))
                .setUpdateCurrent(true)
                .build()
                .schedule();
    }

}
```

**MyJobCreator**

```
public class MyJobCreator implements JobCreator {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Job create(@NonNull String tag) {
        switch (tag) {
            case MyJob.TAG:
                return new MyJob();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String JOB_TAG = "my_job_tag";
    FirebaseJobDispatcher firebaseJobDispatcher;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        JobManager.create(this).addJobCreator(new MyJobCreator());
        MyJob.schedulePeriodicJob();

    }
```